# Code giving warning with CultureInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an code which displays me a warning like :

> Because the behavior of 'string.Format(string, object, object)' could
>   vary based on the current user's locale settings,
>       replace this call in 'MethodName' with a call to 'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])'.
>       If the result of 'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])' will be displayed to the user, specify
>   'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' as the 'IFormatProvider' parameter. 
>       Otherwise, if the result will be stored and accessed by software, such as when it is persisted to disk or to a database, specify
>   'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'.

The code for it is

```
string[] l_array = (from key in nameValueCollection.AllKeys
                    from value in nameValueCollection.GetValues(key)
                    select $"{(key)}={(value)}").ToArray();
return string.Join("&", l_array);
```

I think I can write culture Info, but where and why I require that ?
Or what else should I change.

Answer (score 3):

String interpolation (when you use `$` before a string) is just syntactic sugar for a `string.Format` call and the compiler will basically replace it with one.  You can switch to using the overload of `string.Format` that takes a `IFormatProvider` instead to fix the warning.

```
string[] l_array = (from key in nameValueCollection
                    from value in nameValueCollection.GetValues(key)
                    select string.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                        "{0}={1}", 
                        key, 
                        value)).ToArray();
return string.Join("&", l_array);
```

Comment: I get an error here saying :. `Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type "NameValueCollection'. 'Select' not found. Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'kvp'`.

Comment: @demostack I missread the query.  What you had was correct.  You just need to use the `string.Format` overload to fix the warning.

Comment: I tried Gilgamesh Answer but I still get the same warning.

Comment: I get a warning saying `Method 'A(this NameValueCollection)' calls 'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, object, object)' and does not provide a format item for argument "1, 2". The provided format string is: '"{{0}}={{1}}"`

Answer (score 3):

Edit, it looks like doing `$"{{key}}={{value}}".ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` doesn't work, i've updated my solution.

You can remove this warning with the following:

```
string[] l_array = (from key in nameValueCollection.AllKeys
                from value in nameValueCollection.GetValues(key)
                select InvariantCulture($"{(key)}={(value)}"))
               .ToArray();


   ...
   public static string InvariantCulture(IFormattable formattable)
    {
        return formattable.ToString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Comment: I still get the warning

Comment: Interesting, I was trying to provide an answer with string interpolation but it looks like that may not work, the answer @juharr gave should work in regards to using `String.Format`

Comment: I've updated my solution to include a method that should work assuming you are using `.NET 4.6`